# Completion of space of sequences with finite non zero terms.

Tags: functional-analysis

Problem: Define as $$c_{00}=\{(x_n) \in \mathbb{R}: x_n=0, n>n_0\}  $$ the space of sequences with finite non zero terms.  What is the completion of this metric space with the metric deduced from $l_{\infty}$ ? We remind that $(l_{\infty}, d_{\infty})$ is the space of bounded sequences.

My guess: We know from the theory that $c_{00} $ is inside $l_p$ and i know that $l_p$ with the deduced metric from $l_{\infty}$ is complete. Can I say that $l_{p}$ is the completeness of my space ?

Comment: What is $p$? The guess doesn't make sense without specifying, because the spaces are different for different $p$.

Comment: It is a bit unclear I know, but in my teacher's notes it says $c_00$ subset of $l_p$ subset of $c_0$  subset of $l_{\infty}$. So I guess it is not completely my fault.

Comment: For all $p$ such that $1\leq p<\infty$ it is the case that $c_{00}\subset l_p\subset c_0\subset l_\infty$.  With quantification, this statement makes sense.  However, when trying to identify one specific space, saying it is $l_p$ without specifying $p$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes that is what i meant to write , thanks for your insight :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have it wrong. $l_p$ with supremum-norm is not complete.

The solution you are looking for is $c_0=\{(x_n)\in\mathbb{R}|\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0\}$, i.e. the space of sequences that converge to $0$. You have to show

1. $c_0$ is complete
2. $c_{00}$ is dense in $c_0$

You only need to work with the supremum-norm, no $l_p$ necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know already that $c_0$ is complete so density is what I need to prove. I guess the part that I missed was "the deduced metric".